# couchDB- complex query on a view

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I am using cloudantDB and want to query a view which looks like this

`function (doc) {
  if(doc.name !== undefined){
    emit([doc.name, doc.age], doc);
  }`

what should be the correct way to get a result if I have a list of names(I will be using option 'keys=[]' for it) and a range of age(for which startkey and endkey should be used)

example: I want to get persons having name "john" or "mark" or "joseph" or "santosh" and lie between age limit 20 to 30.

If i go for list of names, query should be keys=["john", ....]
and if I go for age query should use startkey and endkey

I want to do both :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do so. Using the **keys** parameter query the documents with the specified key. For example, you can't only send keys=["John","Mark"]&startkey=[null,20]&endkey=[{},30]. This query would only and **ONLY** return the document having the name *John* and *Mark* with a null age.

In your question you specified CouchDB but if you are using Cloudant, [index query](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html) might be interesting for you.

You could have something like that :

```
{
  "selector": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "name": {
           "$in":["Mark","John"]
         }
      },
      {
        "year": {
          "$gt": 20,
          "$lt": 30
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": [
    "name",
    "age"
  ]
}
```

As for CouchDB, you need to either separate your request (1 request for the age and 1 for the people) or you do the filtering locally.

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks for your response. I am using cloudant, but this article says indexing has a limitation of 200 and then it send s a bookmark of the remaining.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-cloudant-best-practices-multi-tenant-service-trs/                   I have nearly 100k docs in my db

Comment: It has a limitation of 200 docs by request not on the database overall. This mean that if you want to query a total of 400 documents, it will takes you 2 requests.

Comment: yes, you are correct. In my case i have 100k docs. Even if half of them satisfy the query, I will have to make too many requests

Comment: In this case, filtering with a range of age would be the most efficient solution.